Can you kill a Maia?
In S02E01 of The Rings of Power,

orcs try to kill Sauron. He seems to lose his corporeal form, but still survives the attempt.

Which made me wonder : could this be what happens according to Tolkien's writings ? Can Maiar die, and if so how ?
I don't see a lot of examples to work with : elves manage to kill balrogs which may or may not be Maiar (e.g. Glorfindel or Ecthelion), Sauron does not get killed at all either in combat or by Ring destruction. Luthien does threaten to have Huan deprive him of his corporeal form rather than killing him if I remember correctly.
Another example is Saruman, "slain" by Grima but seemingly not dead, as we see his spirit being "refused" by the West, presumably left to wander indefinitely on Middle Earth (cf. this fandom page for instance).
So basically so far it would seem that they may be 100% immortal, except that iirc Gandalf is described as dead and revived rather than disembodied and re-embodied rather fast (in which case the "divine intervention" is much smaller, actually only a matter of speeding things up rather than resurrecting him). His opponent is much more powerful than orcs though, so maybe it plays a role.

The obvious example is Saruman.

@DanielRoseman - Except that they didn't (and couldn't) kill him. He's immortal

It is implied in the books, and stated in lotr.fandom that he's indeed not dead : https://lotr.fandom.com/wiki/Saruman#Fate

Saruman and Gandalf are special cases; they were physically incarnated into "normal" bodies, unlike all other non-Istari cases, where they simply assume a form. In the latter case an Ainur is yes, essentially immortal, but in such cases as Morgoth and Sauron putting all their "will" into materially affecting the world eventually uses them "up" to the degree they can no longer assume physical form.

Maybe you can, I know I couldn't bring myself to.

I don't really see the distinction between "dead" and "incorporeal spirit bound to wander eternally". In either case, he is unable to influence events in the world. We know that the spirits of dead people go to the Halls of Mandos; the only difference in Saruman's case is that he was refused entry to the Halls, but I don't see why that would mean he isn't dead.

@Valorum It's a matter of how you define death. There's one for example, "the severance of spirit from body"/"their severance (which is death)". By this definition, only incarnates may DIE. But do incarnate Maiar count? They aren't naturally incarnate, but can we just talk about the death of their avatar? And by killing the body, severing the spirit from the body, rendering the Maia powerless (for a while, or forever), is s/he dead for the moment?

@gdelab If we define death as "the severance of spirit from body", then Saruman the White is indeed dead, and won't get another body or do anything to the physical world ever again if he shares the same fate of Sauron. If we define death as the total annihilation of the Spirit, then no one (not even a Man) has ever died, 'cause for all we know the Spirits are indestructible.

I didn't find anything in the duplicate page so I'll just comment here. If we define death as "the severance of spirit from body" + the spirit loses the power to rebuild a body or interact with the physical world, then I think yes we can kill a Maia, assuming the Maiar keep coming at us in a physical body. Since "each building-up used up some of the inherent energy of the spirit" (Letters), which means by killing their physical body the Maiar will eventually lose the power to incarnate again, like Sauron, "a mere spirit that ... cannot again grow or take shape".

@Eugene - Sure. If we define death as "what happened to Sauron and Saruman", then yes, they're dead. Note also that it's only the stroke of Tolkien's pen that prevented him from having them return. He was working on as sequel...

@Valorum: Are you saying that there's a universe that could've gone "Lord of the Rings: Book Four: Somehow, Sauron Returned."?

@Valorum I doubt the antagonist would be Sauron though. Tolkien had a "thriller" in mind, "a plot and its descovery and overthrow", and he had already prevented Sauron from coming back through Gandalf's remark.

@Eugene - Authors are remarkably full of shit when it comes to final endings. It's astounding how easy it is to resurrect someone when your agent is offering you a wheelbarrow full of money.

Valar and Maiar are all "spirits" who descended into Arda.  They are bound to Arda until it ends, when they become spirits again.  Spirits are immortal.

@Valorum Thankfully Disney didn't approach (did they) Tolkien to bring back
Sauron somehow, we'll never know whether Tolkien would accept it. But everyone has a price I guess. Tolkien must haven't been paid enough by Ackerman.

@Valorum.  He wasn't "working on a sequel"; he gave up on it!
